# How to change log level in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow

SO far i have tried

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

import logging
import tensorflow as tf
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

None of these seem to work.

Comment: Did you try moving `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'` before `import tensorflow as tf` line? It's possible that tensorflow uses `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` upon import.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity` works.

Please find the code below where `Logging Level` is set to `10 i.e., DEBUG`, meaning only `all the Logs` should be `Printed`:

```
import logging
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.DEBUG)

tf.compat.v1.logging.error('Error Message')
tf.compat.v1.logging.info('Info Message')
tf.compat.v1.logging.warning('Warning Message')
```

As shown below, it has printed all the Log Messages:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Error Message
INFO:tensorflow:Info Message
WARNING:tensorflow:Warning Message
```

Now, let's set the `Logging Level` to `30, i.e., WARN`

```
import logging
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(30) # WARN

tf.compat.v1.logging.error('Error Message')
tf.compat.v1.logging.info('Info Message')
tf.compat.v1.logging.warning('Warning Message')
```

As shown below, `Info` Logs will be Filtered and `Warning and Error Logs` will be printed:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Error Message
WARNING:tensorflow:Warning Message
```

Let's Set the `Logging Level` to `40 i.e., ERROR`

```
import logging
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(40) # ERROR

tf.compat.v1.logging.error('Error Message')
tf.compat.v1.logging.info('Info Message')
tf.compat.v1.logging.warning('Warning Message')
```

Now, we can see that only `Error Message` is printed:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Error Message
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!